# Redux Form post to /user/:id

Tags: redux, redux-form

I am using redux form, but I would like to post the data from the form to this route user/:id.

But my action just get data from the form, what is the best to way to send this id for action create?

```
export async function createUser(props){  

const request = await post(`/users`, props);

return {
    type: CREATE_USER,
    payload: request
  }
}
```

How can I pass the id to change my url to `/users/${id}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see anything here related to redux-form, but assuming your `id` is in your `props` object, you could do:

```
const request = await post(`/users/${props.id}`, props);
```

However, it seems pretty strange that you would even have an `id` if you are creating the user. Usually the primary key is generated upon creation, so what you have already would be just fine, and your server-side CRUD API should be smarter about not expecting an `id`.

Comment: Hi Erick. Actually it was to update, but I tested the create user then, I was using the same action cretion to use the put, but I did not know how to pass more arguments. I was a bit confused about how I pass the function to handleSubmit. However I got some helped and solve it. It was not related to redux-form as you said. Sorry.